# Stop Jenkins pipeline cron trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile as follows

```
node('workers') {
  echo "Running ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"

//   properties(
//     [
//         pipelineTriggers([cron('0 * * * *')]),
//     ]
//   )

  stage('checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('Build') {
      echo 'building'
  }
  stage('Test') {
    echo 'Testing..'
  }
  stage('Deploy') {
    echo 'Deploying....'
  }
}
```

The properties section was not commented out before and I checked it in to test scheduling a Jenkins build from pipeline-as-code. This worked, but now I want to stop the scheduling. Commenting out the code apparently did not work, so how would I go about it?

Comment: Try to build again.  Comments works perfectly in pipeline scripts.

Comment: I have encountered this bug as well. Changing triggers or any job properties inside  the pipeline file will not get picked up right away until you rebuild the job and it sees the new config.

Comment: Jenkinsfile is post-processed. So params/triggers only take affect after they have been built once before

Comment: After I commented out the properties block, I pushed the changes to my repo, and Jenkins rebuilt everything. But at the next hour, a build was still kicked off by a timer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me a call to `pipelineTriggers` with an empty list as argument did the trick:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([]),
])
```

Comment: Before this, I gave the cron a date that would never happen, Feb. 31. I was wondering if there was just a way to remove the schedule all together

Comment: Don't know which Jenkins version you have but for me (Jenkins 1.121.1 with current pipeline plugins) exactly removed the schedule all together as requested.

Answer (score 2):

With declarative pipelines you can use the empty string as the cron schedule to disable.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('')
    }
    stages {
```

then looking at the job configuration, after the pipeline has run, we see:

*No schedules so will never run*